# How do i input a value into an array using a JTextField each time in Java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

i am creating a program in which the user will add the name of someone into the textfield however i created the array which is `String[] studentNames;` but when the user presses submit it will add the name to the array but i want it so that each new text entry will be added to the array elements individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use ArrayList instead of Array, where you would have not fixed-size list.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

// ...

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String text = textField.getText();
        list.add(text);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a static field String[] studentNames in a class and in the ActionListener of your submit button update that array ever time the user inserts a name,

If you don't know the number of names the user will insert prior to allocating the array, you should use an ArrayList